# multiple file upload carrierwave + jquery file upload. error "can't convert nil into string"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I'm trying to make file upload with Carrierwave + Jquery file upload. Carrierwave part went well, however when I want to make multiple upload like shown below it gives me an error "can't convert nil into string":

```
 form_for @prog, :html => {multipart:true} do |f|
   f.file_field :image, name: "prog[image]", multiple: true
   f.submit
 end
```

After submit I get error, but if I remove multipe:true everything works well. I found that this cause is a bug in ruby 2.0.0 edition. I'm using (rails 3.2.1). So, to workaround this problem I tried to use classic html like:

```
 input id="prog_image" type="file" name="prog[image]" multiple
```

So now I can chose multiple files and after submit no error, but how to make form_for block to understand to iterate multiple times through "classic html code" and post every file? now it posting only one at a time even 3 files were chosen.

Comment: Is that a typo on the first line at `:html => {multypart...}`?

Comment: `name: "prog[image]", multiple: true` this is unnecessary thanks can you remove this and try it also can you please put your controller and model code for it

Comment: what do you mean? how than I chose multiple files?

Comment: do not require `name: "prog[image]"` Thanks

Comment: this didn't worked out. still getting error if leave multipart:true. My controller is standard, scaffold generated